# DotNetOpenAuth for previously authorized site

Tags: .net, oauth, dotnetopenauth

I've had great luck with DotNetOpenAuth to do 3 legged authorization.  Currently, I am connecting and pulling in some Google data.

My question is that apparently, if you have already auth'd my web application to your Google account, when I call

```
var accessTokenResponse = google.ProcessUserAuthorization();
```

It basically does nothing.  How do I get the token for an account that has already auth'd my application?  I see no callback of any kind.

I'm chocking this up to my ignorance about OAuth in general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must replace the sample `InMemoryTokenManager` that is included with DotNetOpenAuth with an implementation of `IConsumerTokenManager` of your own that stores the access tokens and secrets in your database.  Then you pass your instance of that interface to the `WebConsumer` class and it will receive all incoming tokens and secrets.

Either when calling `ProcessUserAuthorization` or inside your token manager class, you must also associate the access tokens that you save with the user account of the user who is currently logged into your web site.

Then when the user next visits your site, you look up their user account in your database to get their access token.  And you use it for future requests.  Your `IConsumerTokenManager` will supply the associated token secret as required and life will be good.

Comment: Not to ping an old thread, but I didn't realize the InMemoryTokenManager was a sample intended to be replaced. That might explain some of my own head-scratching around the OAuth implementation of token secrets. Thanks!

Comment: There's an easy egg planted in the `InMemoryTokenManager` sample that's supposed to deliberately break the build if it is lifted from the sample and used elsewhere, with an error telling you to build your own.  Did that not work in your case, @JHubSharp?

Comment: No. In fact, it worked fine for me when the SimpleConsumerTokenManager was breaking because it wouldn't hold on to the access token secret. I'd love it if you could offer some insight to my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12485117/custom-oauth-client-in-mvc4-dotnetopenauth-missing-access-token-secret