# LinkedIn OAuth returns wrong Accesstoken?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, oauth, linkedin-api

I'm using OAuth2 that comes with MVC4 templates by default.

I use Facebook and Google+ authentication today and collect aditional info from them using the access token provided from the Standard OAuthWebSecurity.

Now I'm adding Linked In. When a user connects with Linked In I call different methods (under ExternalloginCallback Method in the Account Controller) depending on the provider.

The LinkedinClient returns the object DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet.AuthenticationResult with extra-data: accesstoken, name, headline and industry.

When I use the accesstoken to get more information about the user, LinkedIn returns "invalid accesstoken".

The accesstoken that is returned turnes out to be the Linked In Oauth User Token, and not the user specific token that I need to have to access more information about the loged in user.

Is there a way without writing a custom Oauth Client to retreive the correct token or does the Client make a call that does not receive the correct token?

Answer (score 0):

So typically when I finally posted my question I found this [Custom OAuth client in MVC4 / DotNetOpenAuth - missing access token secret](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12485117/custom-oauth-client-in-mvc4-dotnetopenauth-missing-access-token-secret) answer which will solve my problem and it seems it would not be possible to intercept the other token in another way.