# dotnetopenauth twitter api 1.1 signed request

Tags: twitter, twitter-oauth, dotnetopenauth

I stuсk on using DNOA library for twitter 1.1 api

```
enter code here
```

I am trying to call users/show.json api

```
    protected override AuthenticationResult VerifyAuthenticationCore(AuthorizedTokenResponse response)
    {
        string accessToken = response.AccessToken;
        string str2 = response.ExtraData["user_id"];
        string userName = response.ExtraData["screen_name"];
        Uri location = new Uri("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/show.json?user_id=" + str2);
        MessageReceivingEndpoint profileEndpoint = new MessageReceivingEndpoint(location, HttpDeliveryMethods.GetRequest | HttpDeliveryMethods.AuthorizationHeaderRequest);
        HttpWebRequest request = base.WebWorker.PrepareAuthorizedRequest(profileEndpoint, accessToken);
        Dictionary<string, string> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        dictionary.Add("accesstoken", accessToken);
        try
        {
            using (WebResponse wresponse = request.GetResponse())
            {
                var str = Utilities.ProcessResponse(wresponse);
                var json = JObject.Parse(str);
                dictionary.AddNotEmpty("name", json.Value<string>("name"));
                dictionary.AddNotEmpty("location", json.Value<string>("location"));
                dictionary.AddNotEmpty("description", json.Value<string>("description"));
                dictionary.AddNotEmpty("url", json.Value<string>("url"));
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
        }
        return new AuthenticationResult(true, base.ProviderName, str2, userName, dictionary);
    }
```

This what is sends to twitter

```
GET https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/show.json?user_id=2193937074 HTTP/1.1
Authorization: OAuth oauth_token="2193937074-cgmZbmJIIb75f7MkQgbdjuvQaen2xzM1WFXXC7G",oauth_consumer_key="XVCgN3fkwzTGgeSm1FBa1Q",oauth_nonce="93UjjRkP",oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1",oauth_signature="YzfXzU3VeEI9xl2SfuknPB33%2FiM%3D",oauth_version="1.0",oauth_timestamp="1389265955"
Host: api.twitter.com
```

The responce is

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
content-length: 63
content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8
date: Thu, 09 Jan 2014 11:12:36 UTC
server: tfe
set-cookie: guest_id=v1%3A138926595613849064; Domain=.twitter.com; Path=/; Expires=Sat, 09-Jan-2016 11:12:36 UTC
strict-transport-security: max-age=631138519

{"errors":[{"message":"Could not authenticate you","code":32}]}
```

The dev.twitter's OAuth tool shows the valid sample of signed header:

```
GET https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/show.json?user_id=2193937074 HTTP/1.1
Authorization: OAuth oauth_consumer_key="XVCgN3fkwzTGgeSm1FBa1Q", oauth_nonce="dbf6f6c1aa6dc226de25265da3d63167", oauth_signature="K3Qfyc9qANFgckQNyqsaDWCnh%2BY%3D", oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", oauth_timestamp="1389266681", oauth_token="2193937074-cgmZbmJIIb75f7MkQgbdjuvQaen2xzM1WFXXC7G", oauth_version="1.0"
Host: api.twitter.com
```

It loook's like the main difference is in length of the oauth_nonce?

DNOA       - oauth_nonce="93UjjRkP"

OAuth tool - oauth_nonce="dbf6f6c1aa6dc226de25265da3d63167"

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem.

The main problem is how the signature is created, the TokenSecret is excluded from it's forming. The core of the this behavior is the AuthenticationOnlyCookieOAuthTokenManager manager that is used inside the base DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet.Clients.TwitterClient class.

```
public class AuthenticationOnlyCookieOAuthTokenManager : IOAuthTokenManager
{
...
    public virtual void ReplaceRequestTokenWithAccessToken(string requestToken, string accessToken, string accessTokenSecret)
    {
        HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("OAuthTokenSecret") {
            Value = string.Empty, //<<< now it's empty
            Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-5.0)
        };
        this.Context.Response.Cookies.Set(cookie);
    }
...
}
```

It's just remove the tokenSecret;

The solution is to use the DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet.Clients.InMemoryOAuthTokenManager class. So you need just derive from OAuthClient and implement proper constructor:

```
public class TwitterClient :  DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet.Clients.OAuthClient
{
    protected TwitterClient(string appKey, string appSecret) : 
        base ("twitter", 
             new DotNetOpenAuthWebConsumer(
                 TwitterServiceDescription, 
                 new InMemoryOAuthTokenManager(appKey, appSecret)))
    { }
...
}
```

Also have found the familiar post [Custom OAuth client in MVC4 / DotNetOpenAuth - missing access token secret](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12485117/custom-oauth-client-in-mvc4-dotnetopenauth-missing-access-token-secret)